# How are objective functions represented in SAT solvers?

Tags: sat, cnf, conjunctive-normal-form

SAT solvers can be used to solve the traveling salesman problem, where the sum of costs between chosen edges is important. I understand that you then ask the solver to go again finding a lesser cost. How is that maximum represented in conjunctive normal form?

Comment: if you put extra materials i would help you.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to translate pseudo-Boolean constraints into CNF and many different encodings are available. A naive encoding is to enumerate all partial models that would result in a higher cost (which is exponential).

Note: I am co-author of the following publication:
You may find the [PBLib](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282359652_PBLib_-_A_Library_for_Encoding_Pseudo-Boolean_Constraints_into_CNF) useful as it provides different encodings.